# BlackBerry RichTextFormatting

Tags: blackberry, java-me, formatting, text-formatting, richtext

I am using the BlackBerry knowledge center tutorial "[How To Format RichTextField](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800345/How_To_-_Format_text_in_a_RichTextField.html?nodeid=800679&vernum=0)" to set a format for my RichTextField.

I encountered some difficulty when formatting text like:

> A I was walking in the street B suddenly I saw a flying dog

If I want to bold only the letters A & B I need to have their string indexes and length.

I created 2 arrays, one handles the indexes of the letters in the entire text and the second array handles the length of each letter index, for example: A (length 1), WC(length 2).

I tried to run it in a loop but it doesn't work:

```
Font fonts[] = new Font[2];
    int[] offset = new int[3];
    byte[] attribute = new byte[3];

    //Get three instances of the default font.
    //On plain, one bold and one bold and italic.
    fonts[0] = Font.getDefault();
    fonts[1] = Font.getDefault().derive(Font.BOLD);

    for (int i = 0; i<lettersLength; i++) {
      offset[0] = letterIndexes[i]; //handles the indexes of the letters in the entire text
      attribute[0] = 1;
      offset[1] = letterLength[i]; //handles each letter index
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide how/where you initalized lettersLength and lettersIndexes? Also, what output you are expecting and getting? Thanks.

Comment: I'm working with a database of letters and text assigned to each letter
I added a letter to a main text string, saved it's length and index according to the entire text and then I added the text associated with the specific letter.

I want to add the main string text (that handles the letters and the text associated with each letter) to a RichTextField and to bold only the letters indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
offsets[0] = 0; // index of A, first character
attribute[0] = 1;  // Choose the bold font starting at offsets[0]
offsets[1] = 1;  // 1 past the desired bold
attributes[1] = 0;  // assign the regular font starting at offset[1]
offsets[2] = index of 'B';
attributes[2] = 1; // set the style to the bold font for this
offsets[3] = index of 'B' + 1; // the new non bold segment starts just after the B
attributes[3] = 0; // set the style to normal
```

Sorry not nicer code, but hope it helps.